# how to convert date from yyyyMMdd format to mm-dd-yyyy format using DateTime.TryParse

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I have a string which contains date in yyyyMMdd format. I want to convert that date into 
system date format, using `ConvertTo.DateTime()` method or any other simple method.

I've used:

```
string time = "19851231";
DateTime theTime= DateTime.ParseExact(time,
                                    Culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDt);
```

it doesn't return anything, Actually I am troubled with Culture info. I don't know in which Culture it exist.

Answer (score 5):

You should almost certainly be specifying `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` - but at the moment that code doesn't look like it would compile at all... it looks like you're trying to do a mix of `ParseExact` and `TryParseExact`, and you're not specifying the format string...

Try:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyyMMdd",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or if you want to use `TryParseExact`:

```
DateTime date;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(time, "yyyyMMdd",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                      DateTimeStyles.None,
                                      out date);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

```
DateTime theTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "yyyyMMdd",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string format = "yyyyMMdd";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

or multiple date formats:

```
string[] formats = {"yyyyMMdd", "dd/MM/yyyy"};
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, formats, 
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: Hi Peer

Thanks for you initiation on this.

I need the culture local id for this kind of date format . I get the date value at runtime.

As 

string time = "RunTime Value";20110714
DateTime theTime= DateTime.ParseExact(time,
                                    Culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out resultDt);

for the  above given code i have used culture with different date string such as dd//mm/yyyy however in another scenario it comes in yyyyMMdd format.So i am quite interested in Culture info of such type of date format.

looking forword with your updates:)

Regards
Sachin Kalia

Comment: You should have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx, are you in a web or application scenario? If you ask a date from a user it is best to use a DateTime control instead of a TextBox.